Why doesn't my SwiftUI coordinate space use .zero as its origin, and how can I make it the base coordinate space of the app?
Why does a custom coordinate space (e.g., "White Screen") in SwiftUI not use .zero as its origin when measured via GeometryReader? Instead, it appears to inherit its position from the global or parent coordinate space. How can I ensure that the custom coordinate space defines its origin at .zero and behaves as the base frame for measurements?
Currently, I am brute-forcing the origin to get what I need, but if this is the only way to set my coordinate space to zero at the top-left, what is the use case for it? I mean, it’s just inheriting from a parent. So, if I’m going to introduce my custom coordinate space to my app, I want all UI elements to inherit from it and for it to become my new custom global system.
P.S. The function that returns the string does not update the view when the state value changes. I'm not sure why; you have to resize the window to see the updated string in the text.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let coordinateSpaceName: String = "White Screen"
    
    @State private var screenCGRect: CGRect = CGRect()
    
    @State private var  bruteForce: Bool = Bool()

    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
                        
            Text(CGRectdescription(id: coordinateSpaceName, rect: screenCGRect)).font(.title3)
            
            GeometryReader { geometryValue in
                
                ZStack {
                    
                    Color.white.opacity(0.5).border(Color.black)
                        .coordinateSpace(name: coordinateSpaceName)
                    
                    Color.red
                        .frame(width: 1.0, height: screenCGRect.size.height)
                    
                    Color.red
                        .frame(width: screenCGRect.size.width, height: 1.0)

                }
                .onAppear {
                    
                    if (bruteForce) {
                        screenCGRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: geometryValue.size)
                    }
                    else {
                        screenCGRect = geometryValue.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName))
                    }

                }
                .onChange(of: geometryValue.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName))) { newValue in

                    if (bruteForce) {
                        screenCGRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newValue.size)
                    }
                    else {
                        screenCGRect = newValue
                    }
                }

            }
            
            Button(bruteForce ? "Geometry Reader Origin" : "Brute Force Origin") {
                bruteForce.toggle()
            }

        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    
    func CGRectdescription(id: String, rect: CGRect) -> String {
        return id + ": (" + String(format: "%.2f", rect.origin.x) + ", " + String(format: "%.2f", rect.origin.y) + ", " + String(format: "%.2f", rect.size.width) + ", " + String(format: "%.2f", rect.size.height) + ")"
    }
    
}


A view can only see a named coordinate space if it is nested inside the container with that named space. So the ZStack cannot see the coordinate space of a child view. See How to use GeometryReader position Rectangle relative to top left corner of another Rectangle In SwiftUI?  for more explanation.

The issue is not whether I am dealing with a child view or a parent view, or where I need to define the coordinate space. The problem lies in the fact that the coordinate space does not actually get its own independent reference frame. Instead, it derives its frame from the NSWindow. As a result, the existence of the coordinate space becomes essentially useless. No matter how we define it, its frame ultimately comes from the NSWindow and does not establish its own standalone origin.

@swiftPunk That's not true. Try moving the coordinateSpace modifier to the VStack or the GeometryReader. frame(in:) returns the correct origin. (0, 0) if you put it on the GeometryReader and (0, 29) if it's on the VStack.

In my answer here, you can see that coordinateSpace clearly is not "useless" and is clearly not the same origin as the window.

I was wrong! You were right. thanks

Coordinate spaces declared by .coordinateSpace(...) are only visible to the children of that modifier. The GeometryReader cannot see .coordinateSpace(name: coordinateSpaceName) because the GeometryReader is its parent view. As a result, it uses the coordinate space of the window as a fallback.
If you put .coordinateSpace(...) on the GeometryReader, then the code works as expected. The origin returned by frame(in:) is (0, 0).
You can also put it on the VStack, in which case frame(in:) will return an origin of (0, 29). 29pt happens to be the distance between the top of the VStack and the top of the GeometryReader.
